# Magento 1.7 or Switch to Magento 2 for PCI complience

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7

Today received notification in Magento Admin Notification panel suggesting to upgrade to Magento 2.0 for (better and faster PCI comlience). 
Given that 1.7.0.2 is the version I run my site, how long do you guys think I can still run Magento on 1.7 version before forcefully be required to upgrade to the latest version Magento 2.0.

To me 1.7 is only 3 years old, but in tech world it could be soon outdated.

Appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It's already outdated. The latest version of Magento 1.x (as of this writing) is 1.9.2.4; 1.7.0.2 was released four years ago.

I hope you're keeping up with security patches. I recommend running your site through http://magereport.com to see what comes out. If you don't know or things come up red, find help to check your site out. There have been a lot of hacks going around, and there's a very high likelihood that any site missing one of a couple particular patches (5344, 6482) has been hacked.

Following that, you should strongly consider updating to the latest 1.x release. It will be a relatively easy jump, and makes sure you aren't missing any features or security fixes.

Switching to Magento 2 won't do a whole lot for you in terms of enhanced PCI compliance. It uses basically the same techniques. However, you would have to basically completely rebuild your site to actually upgrade to it.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I haven't updated to 1.9x version as it may break few things here and there on the site. But I always made sure all patches are installed. Patch vise all safe. I was just wonder much longer can I last on 1.7 before the version will become not complient and unsafe.

Comment: You have another 2.5 years (3 years from M2's release, November 2015) until Magento 1.x is officially EOL (end-of-life) and will no longer be supported or updated in any capacity.

Comment: Great, 2.5y/o is enough time. I think the new migration will be straight to Shopify.

Comment: 1.9 will be an easier upgrade than 2, that's a replatform

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you can migrate to Magento 2 (you have resources to do data migration, make store theme based on m2, all required modules presents for M2) you need did it, because in another case you will loose money on all m1 development.